# Magento 2 - how to add methods to a javascript file by using mixins?

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs, requirejs, mixins

I am using the extension amasty/single-step-checkout. They are using this mixin...

```
vendor\amasty\module-single-step-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\view\shipping-mixin.js (A)
```

...to extend this magento core javascript:

```
vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\view\shipping.js (B)
```

I try to extend the mixin (A) to add a few extra methods, otherwise I would have to override their whole script.

So I created the **requirejs-config.js** file to add my mixin.

**app\code\Company\Shipping\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js:**

```
var config = {

    map: {
        '*': {
            // I am overriding this file with my own, because I needed to replace a line to override a template with app\code\Company\Shipping\view\frontend\web\template\onepage\shipping\methods.html
            'Amasty_Checkout/js/model/one-step-layout':'Company_Shipping/js/model/one-step-layout'
        }
    },

    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Amasty_Checkout/js/view/shipping-mixin': {
                'Company_Shipping/js/view/shipping-mixin-ext': true
            }

      //    I also tried to extend the original script
      //    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': {
      //        'Company_Shipping/js/view/shipping-mixin-ext': true
      //    }
        }
    }
};
```

**app\code\Company\Shipping\view\frontend\web\js\view\shipping-mixin-ext.js:**

### Attempt 1:

```
define([],
    function () {

    return function (Shipping) {
        return Shipping.extend({

            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
            },

            expressMethodActive: function () {
                ...
            },

            test: function() {
                ...
            },
        });
    };
});
```

### Attempt 2:

```
define([],
    function () {

    var mixin = {

        expressMethodActive: function () {
            ...
        },

        test: function() {
            ...
        },
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

Then I call the new methods in the template.

**app\code\Company\Shipping\view\frontend\web\template\onepage\shipping\methods.html:**

```
<li id="opc-shipping_method"
    class="checkout-shipping-method"
    data-bind="fadeVisible: visible(), blockLoader: isLoading"
    role="presentation">
    <div class="checkout-shipping-method">
        <p class="step-title amcheckout-title"
           data-amcheckout-js="step-title"
           data-bind="i18n: getNameShippingMethod()"
           data-role="title"></p>
        <div class="step-content amcheckout-content"
             data-amcheckout-js="step-content"
             data-bind="mageInit: {'checkoutCollapsibleSteps': {}}">
            <div class="amcheckout-wrapper">
                <!-- ko fastForEach: getRegion('before-shipping-method-form') -->
                    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div id="checkout-step-shipping_method">
                    <!-- ko if: rates().length  -->
                        <form class="form methods-shipping" id="co-shipping-method-form" data-bind="submit: setShippingInformation" novalidate="novalidate">
                            <div id="checkout-shipping-method-load">
                                <table class="table-checkout-shipping-method amcheckout-shipping-methods">
                                    <thead class="amcheckout-header">
                                    <tr class="row">
                                        <th class="col col-method" data-bind="i18n: 'Select Method'"></th>
                                        <th class="col col-price" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></th>
                                        <th class="col col-method" data-bind="i18n: 'Method Title'"></th>
                                        <th class="col col-carrier" data-bind="i18n: 'Carrier Title'" colspan="2"></th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody class="amcheckout-items">

                                    <!--ko foreach: { data: rates(), as: 'method'}-->
                                        <tr class="row amcheckout-method"
                                            data-bind="
                                                click: $parent.selectShippingMethod,
                                                css : { '-selected' : $parent.isSelected() == (method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code) }">
                                                
                                            ...

                                            <td>
                                                Test
                                                <pre data-bind="text: $parent.expressMethodActive(method)"></pre>
                                            </td>
                                            
                                        ...
```

But no attempt works. If I go to the checkout then I get

> Message: $parent.expressMethodActive is not defined

Comment: I have ran into this same issue before, it seems that creating a mixin of a mixin doesn't really work as the 'primary' mixin always overrides your 'secondary' mixin making it pointless. I didn't actually try this but I now think that using a shim may work as you can control the order of dependencies - https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471088/requirejs-why-and-when-to-use-shim-config

Comment: Thx for the info. Hmm, not sure how to configure the shim. I think the only way is to override the core code of the Amasty Extension... but I guess update attempts with composer update will fail then...

Comment: You can override the module's JS directly in the theme without using Composer

Answer (score 0):

I think Ben Crook is right. It is not possible. So I have to override the whole script with my own.

I created a new module **Amasty_CheckoutOverrides** and moved all my override templates and javascript files to it. Then I have overridden the files with this requirejs-config.js:

**app\code\Amasty\CheckoutOverrides\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Amasty_Checkout/js/model/one-step-layout':'Amasty_CheckoutOverrides/js/model/one-step-layout',
            'Amasty_Checkout/js/view/shipping-mixin' : 'Amasty_CheckoutOverrides/js/view/shipping-mixin'
        }
    }
};
```

**Important**: If you update the original module for example with `composer update` then you have to check for changes in your overriden files and apply them manually if needed. For example if they patch a security hole, then you have to apply the patch yourself by looking at changes in the files and modify your files accordingly.
Thats why I created a new module named `Amasty_CheckoutOverrides` so that I know on first sight which files I have overriden so I know which files I have to check when I update the module.

Comment: Yes, but you can extend the file, not to copy it completely